# exception error in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class ShakespeareUI extends Application {

  public String Quotes(String fileName) throws Exception{
   File file = new File (fileName);
   String line ="";
   Scanner  sc = new Scanner(file);
   while(sc.hasNextLine()){
      line+= sc.nextLine();
   }
   return line;
  }

  @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
  public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws Exception {


    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

    // Top of Pane with Text 
    Pane paneForText = new Pane();
    paneForText.setPadding(new Insets(0,0,5,0));
    Text shText = new Text(25, 50,"Shakespeare Quotes");
    shText.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 28));
    paneForText.getChildren().add(shText);
    pane.setTop(paneForText);

    // Center of Border Pane with TextArea
    TextArea taQuote = new TextArea();
    taQuote.setPrefColumnCount(30);
    taQuote.setPrefRowCount(5);
    pane.setCenter(taQuote);

    // Bottom of Pane with Buttons
    HBox paneForButtons = new HBox(20);
    Button btLear = new Button("King Lear"); 
    Button btMacBeth = new Button("MacBeth");
    Button btHamlet = new Button("Hamlet");
    Button btRichard = new Button("Richard III"); 
    Button btOthello = new Button("Othello");
    pane.setBottom(paneForButtons);

    paneForButtons.getChildren().addAll(btLear, btMacBeth, btHamlet, btRichard, btOthello );
    paneForButtons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    paneForButtons.setStyle("-fx-border-color: green");


    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 455, 150);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Deep Patel"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage


    ////// Your code here that handles events when buttons are clicked



   btLear.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
         shText.setText(btLear.getText());
         taQuote.setText(Quotes("lear.txt"));
      }
   }); 
   btMacBeth.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
      @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e){
         shText.setText(btMacBeth.getText());
      }
   }); 
   btHamlet.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
      @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e){
         shText.setText(btHamlet.getText());
      }
   }); 
   btRichard.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
      @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e){
         shText.setText(btRichard.getText());
      }
   }); 
   btOthello.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
      @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e){
         shText.setText(btOthello.getText());
      }
   });
   }
   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////// 




  /**
   * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
   * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Hi, I am trying to run this code but there is error about exception. I have no idea what to do. Thanks in advance for any help. I tried to put exception in the override method, in the general method and then I just made new method and put exception there but still the same here

The error that I am getting is this:

> ShakespeareUI.java:79: error: unreported Exception; must be caught or
>   declared to be thrown

Comment: You either need to declare in the method signature that it may throw an exception, or catch and handle the exception in the method.

Answer (score 0):

The `EventHandler` method does not allow you to add a throws clause for non-runtime exceptions. Therefore you need to use `try`-`catch` to handle those exceptions even if you just handle them by rethrowing the exception as `RuntimeException` (which is not a good way to handle failed execution of code in most cases):

```
btLear.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        shText.setText(btLear.getText());
        try {
            taQuote.setText(Quotes("lear.txt"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // TODO: handle exception in a differnt way???
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
});
```

---

Note that you should close any classes accessing files as soon as you're done with the reader/writer. (`Scanner` in this case):

```
public String Quotes(String fileName) throws Exception{
    File file = new File (fileName);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); // builder more efficient for concatenating multiple strings
    try(Scanner  sc = new Scanner(file)) { // try-with-resources automatically calls close on scanner
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            builder.append(sc.nextLine());
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```